# What does "amor non conosce travaglio" mean please?

Tags: translation

I don't trust online translators very much, would much rather speak to people who know what they're on about!

I believe it means *"Love knows no labour"*, is this correct?

Comment: _Love knows no labour_ is correct. Also _Love never gets tired_? Because it is poetic register, you could also invert it and interpret it as _Labour knows no love_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native Italian speaker, I would say, it means "love does not know fatigue/anguish/distress".

Answer (score 1):

> don't trust online translators very much, would much rather speak to
>   people who know what they're on about!
>
> I believe it means "*Love knows no labour*", is this correct?

I suppose that as an Englishman you realize that the translation is not so elegant.

A better translation is "**Love never tires**"

The meaning is obvious, then you can find out if there is a better way to wxpress this concept in your language